# Using clusters to estimate model variance

Tags: variance, predictive-models, prediction-interval, approximation

I am working with a blackbox prediction model which takes known inputs and outputs a single mean response. I know this model's residuals to be heteroskedastic, but also can assume the error term of each response is distributed normally, i.e.
$\epsilon_i$ ~ $N(0, \sigma_i ^2)$.

I am looking to estimate $\sigma_i$ conditional on the data. If I were to use a KNN algorithm on the inputs, then find the RMSE over the subgroup for each point to find a "typical" error conditional on the data, can I expect to have useful results? Or does this break too many assumptions?

Answer (score 0):

kNN makes no assumption about residuals, and in fact, there are no residuals from kNN. Prediction is also supervised, and kNN is an unsupervised method.  kNN can help explore the cluster structure of your predictor data, but the resulting clusters have nothing to with the values or classes of your targets.

What you could do is run kNN using 3NN,5NN,7NN,... (odd k is used to prevent ties) to determine a cluster assignment for each object, and then input that as an additional feature into your prediction, since the cluster structure information may boost the predictive model performance.